# How to return page when function still running Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just started with Spring Boot and have a question about return "index" when the function still running.
Here I have the request

```
@RequestMapping("/run")
String run(Map<String, Object> model) {
    String command = "bash runner.sh";
    runCommand(command, model);

    return "index";
}

 private void runCommand(String str, Map<String, Object> model) {
        //Do something and put into logs and it take a lot of time to running
        try {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", str);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = processBuilder.start();

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\t");
            System.out.println(line); 
        }
        model.put("logs", stringBuffer);
    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  
}
```

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <p>[[${logs}]]</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to access http://localhost:5000/run it will return the index.html instead of waiting for  processing then return the result. Right now, I don't have idea on this so need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Why waiting for processing?

Comment: because I need to show the result after process

Comment: compiler does not processing because you can not work with database to get data in index page and you can not extract the hashmap in your view.

Comment: Yes, do you have solution to change that?

Comment: which data store in `stringBuffer`

Comment: if `stringBuffer` is related to entity show me in your question

Comment: actually, it just a String, when I run the function it will return the String but the function take a lot of time to running

Comment: You have to put full function code to solve problem because in `runCommand(command, model)` there is not data found for `command` argument in `run()` method

Comment: Disregarding the errors pointed out in your example there is nothing asynchronous, i.e. nothing that would continue running after the index was returned. You need to post an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code